# oracle pl/sql compare value against database in function

Tags: oracle, function, exception

I have several names like:

```
john arnold 
edward albert
```

And I have a name dictionary like this:

```
name 
---------------------------  
john   
arnold 
edward
```

I wrote a function to split the name in parts and compare each part against the dictionary (so edward gets compared against the dictionary, then albert will get compared to the dictionary).

My problem is that I would like to return a concatenated string of all the names that don't exist in the dictionary, for example if the name arrives like this:

```
john albert adam gerard
```

It should return:

```
adam gerard
```

I put the names in an array and search for them like this:

```
select name into name_base from usr_pre_pub.nd where name=names(ix);
```

But when a name isn't found on the dictionary, the execution halts and doesn't continue analysing the following names in the array.

```
john (found)  albert(found) adam (not found, exception no data found) gerard (not analysed)
```

I've removed the exception catching part of the function:

```
   exception     
   when no_data_found then
       return ix;
     when others then
     return 'others';
       -- consider logging the error and then re-raise
       raise;
```

But then it just stops and doesn't return a value.

I don't know where to go from here, and hope you can help me on this one.

Comment: im no expert on functions(yet) so i dont know how to do that, that part TOAD adds by itself... sorry if im such a noob..

Comment: please show the full pl/sql block and other relevant informations. We also need to be clarified whether or not you get an actual no_data_found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not catching the exception inside the loop. Assuming that you have a loop to iterate through each of the names in the array, your loop should look something like this.

```
LOOP
   BEGIN
      SELECT name
        INTO name_base
        FROM usr_pre_pub.nd
       WHERE name = names (ix);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         --store the name in variable/array for returning, as not found
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         --do something else
   END;
END LOOP;
```